# .dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot change the size of a document in a capped collection: 311 != 333;

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

using the above code I have created capped collection for my document , while I am doing insert i am facing .dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot change the size of a document in a capped collection: 311 != 333;     How to resolve this

if I manually run db.runCommand( { convertToCapped: 'xx', size: 22193792 } ) in robo3t it working . if I do programmatically then only i got this error

```
 Map<String, Object> commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();
    commandArguments.put(CONVERT_TO_CAPPED,COLLECTION_NAME);
    commandArguments.put(SIZE, 2147483648l);
    BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);
    Document commandResult = database.runCommand(command);}
```

[image]

Comment: The error you have mentioned comes when you try updating a document in a capped collection to the size which is greater than it's originally allocated size. Can you provide the piece of code which is throwing the error

Comment: if(currFileOpt.isPresent()) {
            currFile = currFileOpt.get();
            currFile.setFileStatus(status);
            if(reason.length > 0 && !reason[0].isEmpty())
                currFile.setReason(reason[0]);
            if(status.matches(STATUS_COMPLETED + ApplicationConstants.+ STATUS_FAILED))
                currFile.setMergedTime(new Date());
            xx.save(currFile);

Comment: if i manually convert db.runCommand( { convertToCapped: 'xx', size: 22193792 } )  in robo3t it working . if i do programmatically  then only i got this error

Comment: Can you extract the MongoDB command that was generated by your code?